# Virtual template function in c++

Tags: c++, function, templates, polymorphism, virtual

I have been looking for a way to use both templating and polymorphism at the same time. Here's a simplified version of my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

//*******************************************************************
//*******************************************************************

struct DerivedStuff1
{
    static void eval() { cout << "evaluating DerivedStuff1" << endl; }
};

struct DerivedStuff2
{
    static void eval() { cout << "evaluating DerivedStuff2" << endl; }
};

//*******************************************************************
//*******************************************************************
class BaseClass
{
public:
    template<typename StuffType> virtual void eval() const = 0;
};

class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass
{
public:
    template<typename StuffType> virtual void eval() const
    {
        std::cout << "We are in DerivedClass1: ";
        StuffType::eval();
    }
};

class DerivedClass2 : public BaseClass
{
public:
    template<typename StuffType> virtual void eval() const
    {
        std::cout << "We are in DerivedClass2: ";
        StuffType::eval();
    }
};

int main()
{
    BaseClass* c1 = new DerivedClass1;
    c1->eval<DerivedStuff1>();
    c1->eval<DerivedStuff2>();

    BaseClass* c2 = new DerivedClass2;
    c2->eval<DerivedStuff1>();
    c2->eval<DerivedStuff2>();

    return 0;
}
```

This code does not compile because virtual template functions are not allowed in C++. I found a few approaches to tackle this problem (CRTP, etc.) but none of them were really satisfying. Is there no elegant way to get around that issue?

Comment: you can make class template and use virtual functions inside

Comment: @SemyonBurov - but the template is specific of the method; how can you solve the problem making the class template?

Comment: Why do you need `eval()` virtual?

Comment: You might be able to pull something off by manually creating a vtable (using a `map<string, function_ptr>`) and use `typeid(T).name()` to key off the proper method. This is however going to be slooooow.

Comment: The template types for `eval()` are related in some way? There is a common base (virtual?) class for `DerivedStuff1`, `DerivedStuff2`, etc.?

Comment: @max66 I dont see any specific reason here why not to use class template. May be in context of a problem this is a bad approach, but context isn't included here, so I suggest class templates... In example they look like functors.

Comment: @SemyonBurov - not sure to understand; do you mean a solution like the Filip Kočica's one? Anyway, why don't you propose an example of your idea as solution?

Comment: There is a thing called an X/Y problem.  You have problem Y.  You imagine a solution to it, called X.  You discover a problem with X, and ask how to fix it.  But your real problem is Y.  You don't tell people what Y is, because if only you could solve X you'd have no problem.  But when the solution to X is impractical, this leads to people either describing insane solutions or saying "no".  Your question is about X.  What is Y?

Comment: @max66 Yes, something like that. Why not post as an answer? Because it looks too easy to be a solution :)

Answer (score 7):

The [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) turns run-time polymorphism on its side and makes runtime-polymorphic function templates possible. It has other legitimate uses apart from templatisation, so I guess you can call it somewhat elegant.

Your example can look as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

class DerivedStuff1 {
  public:
   static void eval() { std::cout << "Evaluating DerivedStuff1\n"; }
};

class DerivedStuff2 {
  public:
   static void eval() { std::cout << "Evaluating DerivedStuff2\n"; }
};

class DerivedClass1; class DerivedClass2;
class BaseClassVisitor {
  public:
    virtual void visit(DerivedClass1&) = 0;
    virtual void visit(DerivedClass2&) = 0;
};

class BaseClass {
  public:
    virtual void accept(BaseClassVisitor& v) = 0;
};

class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass
{
  public:
    virtual void accept(BaseClassVisitor& v) { v.visit(*this); }
};

class DerivedClass2 : public BaseClass
{
  public:
    virtual void accept(BaseClassVisitor& v) { v.visit(*this); }
};


template <typename StuffType>
class EvalVisitor : public BaseClassVisitor
{
    virtual void visit(DerivedClass1&) {
        std::cout << "We are in DerivedClass1: ";
        StuffType::eval();
    }
    virtual void visit(DerivedClass2&) {
        std::cout << "We are in DerivedClass2: ";
        StuffType::eval();
    }

};

int main()
{
    EvalVisitor<DerivedStuff1> e1;
    EvalVisitor<DerivedStuff2> e2;

    BaseClass* c1 = new DerivedClass1;

    c1->accept(e1);
    c1->accept(e2);

    BaseClass* c2 = new DerivedClass2;

    c2->accept(e1);
    c2->accept(e2);

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/x6LlLw)

Of course all shortcomings of Visitor apply here.

Comment: I like this approach, but I am just a bit worried about the developer interface. As is, if someone wants to use my code, he needs to create a visitor and pass it to the accept function. Is there no way to encapsulate this a bit further, so that the visitor is not even apparent to the user? Basically, add a template function eval<Stuff>() that would just be there to create the visitor and pass it to the accept function?

Comment: Also, the implementation has been moved from the DerivedClasses to the EvalVisitor now. This will be a problem for me, since these derived classes contain lots of data that they use in the eval functions.

Comment: If you create the EvalVisitor class, you can certainly hide it from the user inside some user-friendly function template. If you want the users to add new functions, they need to be aware of the visitor infrastructure.

Comment: You can also have the actual implementations in (non virtual) member function trmplates of DerivedClassN, and the visitor would just call them. It knows both the specific derived class and specific template arguments to pass so it's not a problem. E.g. `virtual void visit(DerivedClass1& d) { d.eval<StuffYype>(); }`

Answer (score 2):

You could reinvent the vtable and resolve the function pointer at run time. You will, however, have to explicitely instantiate the template on the derived class, but I don't see any approach to this that won't require that.

Quick and dirty example:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
  typedef void (Base::*eval_ptr)();
  using eval_vtable = std::map<std::type_index, eval_ptr>;

  Base(eval_vtable const& eval_p) : eval_ptrs(eval_p) {}

  template<typename T>
  void eval() {
    auto handler = eval_ptrs.find(type_index(typeid(T)));
    if(handler != eval_ptrs.end()) {
      auto handler_ptr = handler->second;
      (this->*handler_ptr)();
    }
  }

  eval_vtable const& eval_ptrs;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived()
     : Base(eval_functions) {}

  template<typename T>
  void eval_impl() {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
  }

  static eval_vtable eval_functions;
};

Base::eval_vtable Derived::eval_functions = {
  { type_index(typeid(int)), eval_ptr(&Derived::eval_impl<int>) },
  { type_index(typeid(float)), eval_ptr(&Derived::eval_impl<float>) },
  { type_index(typeid(short)), eval_ptr(&Derived::eval_impl<short>) },
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  Derived x;
  Base * x_as_base = &x;

  x_as_base->eval<int>(); // calls Derived::eval_impl<int>()
  return 0;
}
```

This won't be exactly **fast**, but it will give you the closest thing to templated virtual functions that I can think of.

**Edit:** For the record I don't advocate anyone use this. I would much rather revisit the design to avoid being painted in this particular corner in the first place. Please consider my answer as an academic solution to a theoretical problem, not an actual engineering recommendation.

Comment: You should use typeindex instead of typeid pointers; typeid pointers are not guaranteed to map 1-1 and onto types.

Comment: I have had fun reading your answer this is so academic as you say!! Actualy working and flexible but so inefficient LOL, I got nostalgia of when I was a PhD student surrounded by professors wasting state money on work that had the merit to make them write papers soon forgotten!!

Comment: Note that in my specific case, speed is not really an issue as this function will only be called a few times here and there. I am much more worried about the developer interface. Regardless of the hidden complexity, I want anyone to be able to use my code without requiring detailed knowledge of its inner working. In light of this, would you still not recommend your approach?

Comment: @Touloudou Sure I guess, if it fits your needs. A few macros could even make this look decent. But since you have to explicitely list all the supported types, you might as well just use a separate virtual function for each type.

Answer (score 1):

Since virtual template methods in C++ arent allowed, you can make a class template and call static function of class template param.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

//*******************************************************************
//*******************************************************************

struct DerivedStuff1
{
    static void eval() { cout << "evaluating DerivedStuff1" << endl; }
};

struct DerivedStuff2
{
    static void eval() { cout << "evaluating DerivedStuff2" << endl; }
};

//*******************************************************************
//*******************************************************************
class BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void eval() const = 0;
};

template<typename StuffType>
class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void eval() const
    {
        std::cout << "We are in DerivedClass1: ";
        StuffType::eval();
    }
};

template<typename StuffType>
class DerivedClass2 : public BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void eval() const
    {
        std::cout << "We are in DerivedClass2: ";
        StuffType::eval();
    }
};

int main()
{
    BaseClass* c1 = new DerivedClass1<DerivedStuff1>;
    c1->eval();
    c1 = new DerivedClass1<DerivedStuff2>;
    c1->eval();

    BaseClass* c2 = new DerivedClass2<DerivedStuff1>;
    c2->eval();
    c2 = new DerivedClass2<DerivedStuff2>;
    c2->eval();

    // deletes

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
We are in DerivedClass1: evaluating DerivedStuff1
We are in DerivedClass1: evaluating DerivedStuff2
We are in DerivedClass2: evaluating DerivedStuff1
We are in DerivedClass2: evaluating DerivedStuff2
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix templates (compile time) and polymorphic (runtime). That's it.

So, a posible workaround is remove templates. For example, it could take a function pointer or just more polymorphism:

```
//*******************************************************************
//*******************************************************************

struct InterfaceStuff{
  virtual void eval() = 0;
}

struct DerivedStuff1 : public InterfaceStuff
{
    void eval() { cout << "evaluating DerivedStuff1" << endl; }
};

struct DerivedStuff2 : public InterfaceStuff
{
    void eval() { cout << "evaluating DerivedStuff2" << endl; }
};

//*******************************************************************
//*******************************************************************
class BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void eval(InterfaceStuff* interface) const = 0;
};

class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void eval(InterfaceStuff* interface) const
    {
        std::cout << "We are in DerivedClass1: ";
        interface->eval();
    }
};

class DerivedClass2 : public BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void eval(InterfaceStuff* interface) const
    {
        std::cout << "We are in DerivedClass2: ";
        interface->eval();
    }
};
```

Another posible workaround is remove polymorphism, just use more templates:

```
struct DerivedStuff1
{
    static void eval() { cout << "evaluating DerivedStuff1" << endl; }
};

struct DerivedStuff2
{
    static void eval() { cout << "evaluating DerivedStuff2" << endl; }
};

//*******************************************************************
//*******************************************************************
class BaseClass
{
public:
    template<typename Eval,typename StuffType> void eval() const
    {
        Eval::eval();
        StuffType::eval();
    }
};

class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass
{
};

class DerivedClass2 : public BaseClass
{
};
```

One way of another, you have to choose one.

Comment: I can write runtime polymorphic template code through a number of means; tyoe erasure, various double-dispatch (or poly-dispatch) strategies, fast casts via CRTP, etc.  Please be more specific when you say something cannot be done; the OP's way of doing it doesn't work, and generally some additional restriction is required if your goal is to avoid reimplementing a c++ compiler in your executable, but "cannot" is a bit strong.  "Should not" usually.