# CPP inheritance with template functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, function-templates

I have the code like this (it's simplified version, really code more complex):

```cpp
class IFoo {
public:
  template <typename T> T GetInc(T x) const { return x; }
};

class Foo : public IFoo {
public:
  template <typename T> T GetInc(T x) const { return x + 1; }
};

class Bar : public IFoo {
public:
  template <typename T> T GetInc(T x) const { return x + 2; }
};

void Print(const IFoo& foo) {
    std::cout << foo.GetInc(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo.GetInc(3.14) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    Print(foo);

    Bar bar;
    Print(bar);

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, it outputs the wrong thing. I can use CRTP here, but then I'll have to template the `Print` function (which I don't want to do)

```cpp
template <typename T> class IFoo {
public:
  template <typename U> U GetInc(U x) const {
    return static_cast<const T *>(this)->GetInc(x);
  }
};

class Foo : public IFoo<Foo> {
public:
  template <typename T> T GetInc(T x) const { return x + 1; }
};

class Bar : public IFoo<Bar> {
public:
  template <typename T> T GetInc(T x) const { return x + 2; }
};

template <typename T> void Print(const IFoo<T> &foo) {
  std::cout << foo.GetInc(1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << foo.GetInc(3.14) << std::endl;
}
```

I don't want to do this, because there are many places where such a call is used and it will complicate it.

I also tried to use the NVI pattern, but I couldn't call the templated function from the base class.

What other solutions are there?
Initially, the problem is to create an interface for a class with template functions

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need a single component that either "knows" *all* the types `T` with which your templates will be instantiated, or "knows" *all* the derived classes of `IFoo`. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: I don't know all T-types (there could potentially be many of them), but I know the derived classes - there are only two of them

Comment: Then it can be implemented with the visitor pattern as in [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45850104/775806), but if it's only two classes, then perhaps a simple handwritten dispatcher with `dynamic_cast` could be preferable.

Comment: You could use `std::variant` with `std::visit`: https://godbolt.org/z/G8G7b9Khb

Comment: Note that when you're using `std::variant`, there's no real need/reason for `Foo` and `Bar` to share a base class either. https://godbolt.org/z/Yf51bsqP4